# H2 select: unexpected type 39 mapping

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I have a mapping issue with an H2 database in MySQL mode.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `USER_BOOKING` (
  `id`         bigint(20) unsigned  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `booker_id`  varchar(36)          NOT NULL,
  `booking_id` varchar(20)          NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id_booker_with_booking` (`booker_id`,`booking_id`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Using MyBatis to select the data like this:

```java
@Select(" select (`booker_id`, `booking_id`) "
        + " from `USER_BOOKING` "
        + "where `booker_id` = #{bookerId};")
@Results(value = {
    @Result(column = "booker_id", property = "bookerId", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.VARCHAR),
    @Result(column = "booking_id", property = "bookingId", javaType = String.class, jdbcType = JdbcType.VARCHAR),
})
List<UserActivityModel> getBookerActivity(@Param("bookerId") String bookerId);
```

Calling `getBookerActivity` ends up with this exception:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]
### The error may exist in foo/bar/user/activity/infrastructure/UserActivityWriteStorage.java (best guess)
### The error may involve foo.bar.user.activity.infrastructure.UserActivityWriteStorage.getBookerActivity
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: select (`booker_id`, `booking_id`)  from `USER_BOOKING` where `booker_id` = ?;
### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [HY000]; error code [50000]; General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]
### The error may exist in foo/bar/user/activity/infrastructure/UserActivityWriteStorage.java (best guess)
### The error may involve foo.bar.user.activity.infrastructure.UserActivityWriteStorage.getBookerActivity
### The error occurred while handling results
### SQL: select (`booker_id`, `booking_id`)  from `USER_BOOKING` where `booker_id` = ?;
### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]
; uncategorized SQLException; SQL state [HY000]; error code [50000]; General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
    ...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39" [50000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: type=39
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:293)
...
```

(an insert works fine)

Type `39` is a `ROW` type, while I would expect a `STRING` (type `13`).

I can't get why I obtain this `ROW` mapping: is there a parameter tweak I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` SELECT (`booker_id`, `booking_id`) … `` returns one column of the ROW data type in H2 (and MySQL doesn't support such construction at all). It looks like you added these parentheses accidentally and your query should be `` SELECT `booker_id`, `booking_id` … `` without them.